# Duplicate key exception when updating (not inserting) a field in a DB table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a trigger for a table (Person) so that each time a new Person entry is created its ID is inserted in another table (Person_ID). Person_ID table has only 2 rows: ID (primary key, int and Identity) and Person_ID (GUID whose values is passed with the trigger).
This schema cannot be changed due to other dependencies with our business logic.

Now I need to update a field of Person table with the Person_ID.ID (the identity automatically generated once that person has been created). To do that I created a trigger for Person_ID so that once a new entry is created, the generated ID will updated the target field in Person table:

```
UPDATE Person
SET target_Person = (SELECT JPerson_ID.ID FROM inserted)
WHERE Person.ID IN (SELECT JPerson_ID.PersonID FROM inserted)
```

When I create a new Person I get the following exception:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'TBL_PERSON_A_PK'. 
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TBL_PERSON_A.
```

There is an update trigger associated to table Person that comes from a legacy component and I cannot edit or see it (it is encrypted). It seems the reason of the exception above.

**Why do I get this exception even if I simply make an UPDATE and not an insert?**

To solve this I disable such a trigger before executing the update and then enabling it again and it works like a charm:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'DISABLE TRIGGER dbo.TBL_PERSON_TRU1 ON PERSON'
...
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'ENABLE TRIGGER dbo.TBL_PERSON_TRU1 ON PERSON'
```

However how can I be sure that this will not bring to logic errors?
Thanks.

Comment: Without being able to see what the UPDATE trigger is actually doing, I doubt you will be able to diagnose this problem further.

Comment: Besides the issues you're running into, your own trigger code is broken - it assumes that `inserted` only contains a single row, which isn't a generally safe assumption.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: the select return only one record (please see answer to Tim, below). I forgot to tell that I used that 2 scripts too.
Unfortunately the UPDATE trigger is encrypted therefore I cannot see its behaviour. However the target field that will be updated is an old one, no more used, therefore I "assumed" that it would be enought safe even without knowing what the UPDATE trigger does.

Comment: no, if someone runs `UPDATE Table SET ABC = DEF WHERE PK in (1,2)` then an UPDATE trigger on Table will see an `inserted` table with two rows in it (similarly for statements that insert or delete multiple rows), and your UPDATE statement inside the trigger (that assumes only a single row in inserted) will break.

Comment: @Damien: thanks for the explanation. Maye I could then use a condition or TOP 1 statement to ensure to have just one record. In this way it would not break, even if it might not be completely correct if the UPDATE trigger retrieves 2 records.
Could you otherwise suggest a different approach, considering that I cannot see the UPDATE trigger? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this causes your problem, but have you kept in mind that your `(SELECT JPerson_ID.ID FROM inserted)` could return more than one row?

So you insert trigger must be changed to somewhat like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgJPerson_ID] ON [dbo].[TBL_PERSON_A]
FOR INSERT
AS

INSERT INTO dbo.JPerson_ID(ID )
    SELECT ID FROM inserted
```

and accordingly the delete-trigger(if you have one)

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgJPerson_ID] ON [dbo].[TBL_PERSON_A]
FOR DELETE
AS

DELETE FROM dbo.JPerson_ID
    WHERE ID IN(SELECT ID FROM DELETED)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I did not specified in the question, but I have already two triggers (INSERT / DELETE) like the ones you suggested. Therefore SELECT JPerson_ID.ID FROM inserted returns just one record (I also double checked querying the Person_ID table).

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood, you seem to have answered your own question; it appears that the trigger you can't see the definition of is doing something to prevent the update statement from completing.

Without knowing what that trigger does I can't see how we can help you.

As a side note, I don't understand why you are updating the `Person` table with the `ID` from the `Person_ID` table.  It seems a bit pointless really as you can just join on to the `Person_ID` to retrieve the `ID`

```
Select p.ID, -- The Person GUID
       p.Name,
       pi.ID -- The Person_ID ID

From dbo.Person p
Join dbo.Person_ID pi on p.ID = pi.PersonID
```

Comment: In the moment I create (using Linq/c# code) a new person I do not know which ID it will have, since this is the identity of table Person_ID and will be created just after the INSERT with the trigger.
Therefore I planned to create a new trigger that would make an UPDATE on the "parent" table once the ID (in Person_ID) would be available. Hope it would be more clear now. Thanks